# Erlang start gen_server blocked code

Tags: erlang, spawn, gen-server

I have gen_server in my erlang code. And when i try to run it the next code after this don't work. For example:

```
.......
my_server:start_link().
io:format("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"),
.....
```

Now io:format/1 don't work. And if i run gen_server with spawn:

```
......
spawn(fun() -> my_server:start_link() end)
io:format("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
......
```

Now io:format worked. Why?

Thank you.

Comment: What does your `start_link` function look like? Has the server started properly and can receive requests?

Comment: Please provide more relevant code.

Comment: I'm suspecting that your `my_server:start_link/0` never returns. Check the function and make sure it returns some value eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the `start_link` function in your `my_server` module calls the `gen_server:start_link/3` or `gen_server:start_link/4` function.

The `gen_server:start_link` will in turn call the `init` function of your `my_server` module. I guess your `init` function is a blocking call which is the reason why your initial code piece doesn't return.